# __construct() must be an instance of Post\Model\PostTable

Tags: zend-framework3

Try add new module? but got are error:

> Argument 1 passed to Post\Controller\PostController::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Post\Model\PostTable, none given, called in
>   W:\domains\zend_blog\skeleton-application\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\Factory\InvokableFactory.php

```
namespace Post\Controller;    
use Post\Model\Post;
// Add the following import:
use Post\Model\PostTable;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;



class PostController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $table;
    /**
     * Execute the request
     *
     * @param  MvcEvent $e
     * @return mixed
     */

    // Add this constructor:
    public function __construct(PostTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel([
            'post' => $this->table->fetchAll()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Post Table:

```
<?php

namespace Post\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
class PostTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
       // $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }

    public function getPost($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function savePodt(Post $album)
    {
        $data = [
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        ];

        $id = (int) $album->id;

        if ($id === 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return;
        }

        if (! $this->getPost($id)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Cannot update album with identifier %d; does not exist',
                $id
            ));
        }

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deletePost($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(['id' => (int) $id]);
    }
}
```

Module:

```
namespace Post;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface,ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    /**
     * Expected to return \Zend\ServiceManager\Config object or array to
     * seed such an object.
     *
     * @return array|\Zend\ServiceManager\Config
     */
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Model\PostTable::class => function($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\PostTableGateway::class);
                    return new Model\PostTable($tableGateway);
                },
                Model\PostTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Post());
                    return new TableGateway('post', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getControllerConfig() {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\PostController::class => function($container) {
                    return new Controller\PostController(
                        $container->get(Model\PostTable::class)
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a duplicate setting for the controller factory in the **module.config.php**. Check:

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\PostController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            ...
        ],
],
```

Remove line:

```
Controller\PostController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
```

so that the factory method in your Module.php is used.